# Dynamics display name vs field name

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, field

I'm carrying out some basic javascript validations on a Dynamics 2011 form.
I have a small check when the form is marked as "complete" that ensures, after a save, that mandatory fields have been entered.  This is checked with the below code:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_form001_sec1_q1").setRequiredLevel("required");
```

Problem is, the field name isn't great, and when the message "You must provide a value for new_form001_sec1_q1" appears to the user, it doesn't look good.  I was wondering if I can set this messagebox to use the fields display name instead, which in this example could simply be "Question. 1".

Thanks!

Comment: normally the alert shows the label of the field, not the name, which is the label of the field "new_form001_sec1_q1"?

Comment: Yes, apologies!  It is showing the label of the field, I can easily edit this.  Thanks, only realized this before I read your comment. Thanks. :)

Comment: @GuidoPreite your comment needs to be an answer...

Comment: @Daryl it's just an oversight, GrumP can reply and marks as confirmed answer, I think will be more accurate in this way :)

Comment: @GuidoPreite I don't think it matters who the answer comes from, and if you're smart enough to realize the simple answer that was overlooked, you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the answer after I posted the question.

The warning shows the label of the field (not the schema name), and it can be editable in the properties of the field.